# Grails Spring Security - Load "interceptUrlMap" dynamically

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

In the Grails Config.groovy we have defined "interceptUrlMap" like:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
'/': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
'/login/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

These values  are hardcoded. I just wanted to load this interceptUrlMap from database. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just check out [official docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#requestmapInstances). You should use:

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Requestmap"`

and then for example:

`new Requestmap(url: '/profile/**',    configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER').save()`

Comment: this approch is to save the defined url map to the DB. i have user defined table and just want to fetch those values from DB and put it to the map (interceptUrlMap).

Comment: I do not understand what do you want to achieve. What exactly do you want to load from db? Could you provide an example in question?

Comment: I have table for these configurations and i have user interface to manage these url and roles. I dont want to hard code the url and role details in server side like "Requestmap" do. To add new url and role i need to edit the groovy file so this will be problem when the application is running on production. The server should not restarted because of adding new values. From the user interface i will add the new url and role and then it should save in the DB and it should reload the spring security configuration.